# What tests are made in an Ingress Protection to verify that no water entered the enclosure?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, waterproofing

I am asking this question on what tests are made to to verify that no water has penetrated the waterproof enclosure during an Ingress Protection test.  I have researched tests online and most often this is done simply by a visual inspection.  Is a visual inspection an acceptable method as it could be very subjective if a small amount of water penetrates.  Another method which I could think of is to weigh the item before and after the test and verify that no water has seeped in but this method would require a high accuracy scale which I do not have at my disposal. Can someone please suggest another method or if a visual inspection is considered enough by the industry?

Comment: There are of course standard tests. Beyond my knowledge, so here's [a YouTube video](https://youtu.be/_DooiH4BCZo). The gentlemen talk at length, but some water does eventually get sprayed. It appears to be visual inspection after that.

Comment: Often done with a pressure test with air ,argon, etc; , then look for bubbles with soapy water.

Answer (score 2):

Pure weight test before and after may not be accurate as the enclosure may have absorbed some water without it entering. Apply dye around areas where ingress is possible, if it washed away there has been ingress. Depending on the volume/internal geometry of your enclosure a visual inspection is generally acceptable for IP ratings in my experience.